# What does parentheses in a type definition represent?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In React's `index.d.ts` file, the following interface definition is listed. What is the meaning of the third line? `(props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null;`

```
type SFC<P = {}> = StatelessComponent<P>;
interface StatelessComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null;
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The interface describes a function and the first definition is the signature. Those values inside the parentheses are the arguments and `ReactElement<any> | null` is the type that is returned.